# multiply all float values of a column in table, If a value is null or negative or not numeric, raise an error in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I need to multiply all float values of a column in table if the column value is positive.
If I find a value is null or negative or not numeric, I raise an error in SQL server 2008 R2.

given table t0:

```
   col
   1.5 
    2
```

given table t1:

```
    col
     2
    -1
     5
     0
    null
    NaN
```

For t0 I should get 3, for t1, I should raise  an error.

```
  DECLARE @ta float
  SELECT CASE @float 
    when tableName.col <= 0 then raiseError
    when tableName.factor IS NULL  then raiseError
    ELSE multiply(tableName.col)
    END
FROM tableName
```

I know that I can use exp(sum(log(isnull()))) ,but, for floating point calculations, it is not efficient. Are there more efficient ways to do it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which field type are you using since you can store NaN?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson10, bacuse the table is provided by others, i assume that the valuse may be messed up. I need to consider all corner cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Col DECIMAL(18,2),
    @Result DECIMAL(18,2) = 1

DECLARE X CURSOR FOR
SELECT Col 
FROM YourTable
OPEN X
FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @Col
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
    IF (@Col<=0)RAISERROR('Your Message',16,1)
    IF (@Col IS NULL )RAISERROR('Your Message',16,1)
    -- Your Condition
    SET @Result = @Result*@Col
    FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @Col
END
CLOSE X
DEALLOCATE X


PRINT @Result
```